# HTML - Set value for the Select dropdown

Tags: html, forms, select

I have a select dropdown menu and I want the placeholder text to read 'Position'

```
<select id="playingPosition" value="Position">
<option value="goalkeeper">Goalkeeper</option>
<option value="defender">Defender</option>
<option value="midfielder">Midfielder</option>
<option value="striker">Striker</option>
</select>
```

When the page loads, 'Goalkeeper' will be displayed before any user input. I have tried to rename this to 'Position' using the value attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/bHJM2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
```

This becomes:

```
<select name="playingPosition" id="playingPosition" value="Position">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="goalkeeper">Goalkeeper</option>
    <option value="defender">Defender</option>
    <option value="midfielder">Midfielder</option>
    <option value="striker">Striker</option>
</select>
```

Looks like:

[image]

And we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `selected` attribute on the `option` element you want to select like this:

```
<option value="defender" selected>Defender</option>
```